# PlayerChatTabCompleteEvent deprecated in Spigot 1.16.1

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, deprecated, bukkit

I could not find a replacement for the deprecated **[PlayerChatTabCompleteEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerChatTabCompleteEvent.html)** that is deprecated in the newest Spigot 1.16.1 Version.

I already checked the docs, but could not find anything related to that.

And no, I don't want to use a **@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")** at the beginning of my event.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to handle tab completion for a command, that is still possible through TabCompleter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no replacement. Since 1.13 the client does not tell the server when they press tab in chat.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Most deprecated methods work, they are just not being updated, works for me.

Just suppress the warning and try it, if it doesn't work, use something else for accesibility

I've done it plenty of times and it worked